# SOQL query to find out if user exists in public group in Javascript

Tags: soql, javascript

Can anyone help me to query whether the current user is a member of public group in Javascript button on click. I've gone through many blogs but nothing struck to my eyesight which will be of help. If the result is success i.e if user exists in a public group i'll be executing some functions else no event occurs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay I'm able to query the userId. Thanks guys and the code used by me goes below.

Comment: var user = sforce.connection.getUserInfo();
alert(user.userId);

Answer (score 1):

The SOQL for this remains same whether you write in apex or JS .Here is the correct SOQL for same

```
List<GroupMember> lstgroupmember = [Select UserOrGroupId, Group.Type, GroupId From GroupMember g where Group.type = 'Regular' AND UserOrGroupId='YourUserID' LIMIT 1];
if(lstgroupmember.size()>0){
  //fun
}else{
  // keep quiet
}
```